# how to remove/replace a substring like match to the expression like %[%]% from a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `message` which have expression like [ example] or [bla bla]. Basically, I want to remove braces `[]` as well as all text between the braces.
For example:

```
input: its a string [text to remove including braces] to replace.
output: its a string to replace
```

I have tried alot of solutions, but still not working

```
UPDATE resource SET message = REPLACE(message,'%[%]%','')
```

Comment: Please, provide DBMS you're using and tag your question with it. SQL is just a language.

Comment: i am using mysql with phpmyadmin. its an sql language question so i taged only sql

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function. You can provide a pattern to match a substring you like.

Here is an example:

```
select regexp_replace('its a string [text to remove including braces] to replace.', 
                      '\\[[^\\]]*\\]', -- the pattern
                      '');
```

Output:

```
its a string to replace.
```

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanakram, which version of MySQL are you using? And what is the error exactly?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: #1064  you have an error in syntax; check manual for version for the right syntax to use near '(' its a string [text to remove including brace] to replace.', at line 1.

Comment: i used my table name between select and regexp_replace

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanakram, `REGEXP_REPLACE` function is available since version 8.0. So if possible, upgrade to a newer version of MySQL. If not, you may want to create a user-defined function. In this case look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one pair of square braces, you can use:

```
UPDATE resource
    SET message = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '[', 1),
                         SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, ']', -1)
                        )
    WHERE message LIKE '%[%]%';
```

Comment: thanks Gordan Linoff. but it does not working well. left brace remains in string. and sometime it removes all data after left brace